# PHP file_get_contents() is not working and showing gethostbyname failed error. How to fix it?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to make a simple web crawler with PHP. I have tried with file_get_contents(). But its not working properly. It's showing a error like below.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0 in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/search/crawl.php on line 12

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.wikipedia.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0 in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/search/crawl.php on line 12

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/search/crawl.php on line 38
```

What does it means?? And also the code on line 12 is

```
$mainUrl = "http://www.wikipedia.org";
$str = file_get_contents($mainUrl);
```

Code on line 38,

```
$all_links = implode(",",$sec_url);
```

So how to fix this now??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump(ini_get("allow_url_fopen"));` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with https and be sure you allowed in php.ini : allow_url_fopen=1

```
$mainUrl = "https://samplesite.com";
$str = file_get_contents($mainUrl);
```